# Processing/sorting mail from a mailbox-file?

Tags: email, procmail, fetchmail

I got a mailbox-file ("Mboxrd") created by `getmail`, and I'd like to "process" it by sorting mail from various (groups of) senders, and move them to separate mailbox-files (I guess 3-5 for now).  Ideally, the mail messages thus moved, should be deleted from the original mailbox-file.

I most likely would want to classify mail by the sender-address - although being able to classify it by Subject (ie. certain words/phrases) would also be nice...

Now, if this had been messages just received on my computers MTA - or if I'd set-up `getmail` to deliver mail to the MTA - I guess I could use `procmail` the normal way...  However, what I got is a "dead" file with already stored mail-messages, so that's not an option.  I guess I could send the mail through the MTA, but surely there must be a way to process the mail as it is (in the file)?

So, is there a program or command - or some special options to `procmail` or a similar command - that lets me "sort" the mail in a mailbox-file into several other mailbox-files, based on the sender/subject of the messages?  A small example (eg. of the config-file) would also be appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `formail -s` method is documented with a demo script in the [`procmail` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/procmail); look for this phrase:

> Procmail  can  also  be invoked to postprocess an already filled system mailbox.

You would also find this in http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#split

If your mailbox is not a Berkeley mbox single file, chances are you have a directory where each file is an individual message.  In this case, you can process it simply with

```
for f in folder/*; do
    procmail -options <"$f"
    # maybe rm "$f" to remove the original after processing completes
done
```

As an example of how to filter by sender, a simple recipe would be something like

```
# If your mailbox destination is maildir, no locking is required
:0:  # so you could lose the second colon here, and in subsequent examples
* ^From:.*\<alice@example\.com\>
alice

:0:
* ^From:.*\<bob@example\.net\>
bob
```

etc.  This examines the "From:" header which is usually what people mean by "sender", though there are two other fields in common use (the envelope sender, which is usually in `Return-Path:`, and the actual `Sender:` header which is optional, but frequently populated by the sending software when the `From:` header is not the actual sender).

Similarly, to classify by `Subject:`, simply specify a regex which matches the subjects you want to capture.

```
:0:
* ^Subject: *((Fwd?|Re): *)*\[gunk]
gunk-list
```

would find messages with Subject headers which contain the label `[gunk]`, optionally preceded by whitespace and/or `Re:` and/or `Fw:` and/or `Fwd:`.

Comment: If you need help crafting regular expressions for specific patterns, probably post a separate question with more detailed requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your mailbox file is in the mbox format, you can use the `formail` utility that comes with procmail to run a command on each mail, with the `-s` option to tell it that the input is a mailbox and not just a single mail. That command can be `procmail` if you want to apply your procmail rules, or it can be anything else that receives the mail on standard input and does whatever it wants with it.

```
formail -s procmail <Mboxrd && mv Mboxrd Mboxrd.done
```

Another approach would be to load the mailbox in mutt and apply some macros. This has the advantage of being agnostic to the mailbox format, but has the downside that mutt macros can be cryptic (not necessarily more cryptic than procmail rules though). Another advantage of using mutt is that it can move one mail at a time, so if it's interrupted midway, it can resume where it left off.

Comment: Just beware that `procmail` hasn't been updated in 15+ years.  It has well-known, nasty security vulnerabilities.  Its last die-hard supporters gave up on it and run for the hills some 5+ years ago.  FWIW.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Actually, we are still here

Comment: @tripleee That isn't really something to be proud of in 2017. :)

Comment: @SatoKatsura Feel free to post an answer showing how to do this with Sieve or Maildrop or whatever it is you are trying to advocate between the lines here.

Comment: @tripleee Not trying to advocate anything, just a quick [reminder](https://www.google.com/search?q=procmail+vulnerability).